# Need help with Http Post method

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, apexrest

I am new to Integration and I have a business requirement to integrate with a third party that has a request structure in the below form format :

```
Request: 
{
    "CaseId" : "123",
    "Subject" : "Leave Changes",
    "Description" : "leave Description",
    "From" : "ABC@From.com",
    "To" : "PQR@To.com"
}
```

My class :

```
global class NLPCallout_Cases {

    @future (callout=true)
     public static void NLPCallout_Cases(id ccid,String Subject,String Description, String To) {


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        String endpoint = ('endpoint');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
        system.debug('CC ID' +ccid);
        List<Case> caselist = new List<Case>();
        caselist =[select id,Subject, Description,From__c,To__c from Case where id=:ccid];
        for(Case cc : caselist){
            system.debug('without pretty'+JSON.serialize(cc));
            String JsonString=JSON.serialize(cc);
            req.setBody(JsonString);
            system.debug(req);

            //system.debug(req.setBody(Body1));
        }
        //Http response method 
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }
}
```

Trigger :

```
trigger IdentifyCasesAsJunk on Case (after insert) {
    for (Case cc : Trigger.new) {
       if (cc.subject!=null && cc.Description!= null) {
            NLPCallout_Cases.NLPCallout_Cases(cc.Id,cc.Subject,cc.Description,cc.To__c);
            System.debug('cc.Id');
            System.debug('cc.From__c');
            System.debug('cc.To__c');
        }
    }
}
```

In response I am getting Invalid request Missing Key "To". Also I am not able to set From. Can someone please help me to form my request correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JSON.serialize you will get String as below. Which is not what the third party is expecting.

```
{
    "Id" : "50090000009JUmQ",
    "Subject" : "Leave Changes",
    "Description" : "leave Description",
    "From__c" : "ABC@From.com",
    "To__c" : "PQR@To.com"
}
```

I hope you can see it in debug log.

You have to generate your JSON as:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
// Write data to the JSON string.
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('CaseId', cc.Id);
gen.writeStringField('Subject', cc.Subject);
gen.writeStringField('Description', cc.Description);
gen.writeStringField('From', cc.From__c);
gen.writeStringField('To', cc.To__c);
gen.writeEndObject();

// Get the JSON string.
String pretty = gen.getAsString();
System.debug( '----> JSON: '+pretty);
```

Comment: Serializing an `SObject` won't exactly produce the output you described (everything is contained within an 'attributes' object, and there are a few more fields that are included such as the record's URL), but the point remains that _serializing an `SObject` doesn't result in what most people would expect_. Using the `JSONGenerator` class is certainly an option, but it is far from the _only_ option (and usually not the shortest/simplest). Still, this answer is enough for a +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to generate specific JSON is to use a map. This is a bit more compact and leaves the handling of various field types up to the `serialize` method:

```
Case c = [select ... from Case where id = :ccid];
Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>{
    'CaseId' => c.Id,
    'Subject' => c.Subject,
    'Description' => c.Description,
    'From' => c.From__c,
    'To' => c.To__c
};
String s = JSON.serialize(m);
```

Also always good to check the [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the `HTTPResponse`:

```
if (res.getStatusCode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() < 300) {
    // Worked
} else {
    // Handle error
}
```